# what is the expectation value and variance of a sum of absolute random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

let $M = \langle |m_1 + m_2+...+m_N| \rangle, M^{\prime} = \langle |m_1| + |m_2| +...+|m_N| \rangle$ and $M^{''} = \langle |m_1| \rangle$, where $m_i$ are random variables. and $\langle...\rangle$ represents expectation value. is there any relationship between values $M, M^{'}$ and $M^{''}$?

other information:

$\langle m_1 + m_2+...+m_N \rangle = 0$.

$m_i$ are identical random variables but they are correlated.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! To make your question better please describe your attempt at solving the question

Comment: What do $\langle \cdots \rangle$ represent?  Ignoring them, I doubt there is an general relationship, but you can presumably say $E[M^\prime] \ge E[M]$ and $E[M^{''}]=\frac1N E[M^\prime] \ge \frac1N E[M]$

Comment: $\langle ... \rangle$ represent expectation value

Comment: @GradaGukovic - Your suggested counterexample does have $E[M''] = \frac{1}{N} E[M']$.  A counterexample which would not would be $m_i \sim U[0,i]$ or other many cases where the $m_i$ are not identically distributed

Comment: If $\langle \cdots \rangle$ is an expectation value then $M$ etc are values, not random variables with distributions

Comment: oh sorry, yes you are right. I mean the value of $M, M^{'}, M^{''}$

Comment: Welcome to stack exhange = ) Maybe you can start looking for inequalities using the well now algebra result $|x+y|\leq |x| + |y|$. And mind the linearity of the expectation function!